# Configuring hadoop in Local Mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Hi I had successfully installed hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode on a VM. I am writing code in eclipse and than exporting as jar file onto hadoop cluster and than doing debugging there. Now just for learning purpose I was trying to install hadoop in local configuration mode on my windows machine. By doing this I will be able to do testing without going through all the hassle of creating jar files,exporting and do testing on hadoop cluster.

My question is can anyone help me in understanding how hadoop will work in local mode ( hdfs vs local file system ) on windows and How I can configure hadoop in local machine on the windows machine ( what steps I can follow).

I tried following various blogs for doing same but was not able to understand much from them. So posting here the same.

Let me know if any-other information is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cant use hadoop on windows from the get go - however, you can use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to achieve effectively the same thing.

I managed to set up local mode and distributed mode running directly from cygwin, however was unable to get pseudo-distributed to work nicely due to various cygpath conversion issues between Unix and Windows path styles.

However, in practise I still make the jars and send them straight across to the cluster using `rsync`, as it is much faster once your project reaches a certain magnitude for testing and remote debugging can be done from eclipse on windows to the linux cluster.